# Is there any way to achieve Graph by Branch feature through git log?

Tags: git

What I want to achieve is a Git graph log where each branch has one single column allocated to it.

```
$ git log --graph --all --topo-order --decorate --oneline --boundary \
    --force-branch-columns=master,dev
```

```
    * f745bf5 (HEAD, newbranch) Merge branch 'master' into newbranch
   /|                                                               
  / * 7031537 commit                                                
 /  * 416ab2c commit                                                
| * | a9f8d93 (dev) Merge branch 'master' into dev                  
|/| |                                                               
* | | 5f32650 (master) commit                                       
| * | b511501 Merge branch 'master' into dev                        
|/| |                                                               
* | | 4e6810e commit                                                
| * | 2cd55b4 Merge branch 'master' into dev                        
|/|/                                                                
| /                                                                 
|/|                                                                 
* | 4f74695 commit                                                  
| * 372799e Merge branch 'master' into dev                          
|/|                                                                 
* | 076669f commit                                                  
 \|                                                                 
  * 7382440 initial empty commit
```

This is where I found some results but not a way to implement any:
https://gist.github.com/michaelhood/5075495

```
$ git log --graph --all --topo-order --decorate --oneline --boundary \
    --force-branch-columns=master,dev
```

Answer (score 4):

There is not—but it's also worth noting that such a feature would be misleading.

The fact that commit `4e6810e`, for instance, is on branch `master` does not change the fact that commit `4e6810e` is on branch `newbranch`.  Many commits are on many branches simultaneously.  The set of branches that contain any one commit *C* changes over time as branch names are created and destroyed.

The *graph* remains constant throughout.  It's just the *labels*—the branch names—that change.<sup>1</sup>  The statement *commit C is on branch B* simply means that by starting at the commit identified by name *B*, and working backwards through all paths through the history formed by the commit graph, Git can reach commit *C*.

Git does have the notion of working backwards through the graph but following only the *first* parent at each merge.  That is, given a graph like:

```
...--o--o--o--o---o--o   <-- name1
      \          /
       o--o--o--o   <-- name2
```

one can have Git start at the tip commit identified by `name1` and walk backwards through both rows of commits, or start at the tip commit identified by `name1` and walk backwards only along the top row (assuming that the first parent of the merge is along the top row).  To achieve this, `git log` and `git rev-list`—the two principle graph-walking commands—have the option `--first-parent`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For instance, after deleting the name `master`, commit `4e6810e` would no longer be on `master` (which no longer exists).

Answer (score 2):

You can get close with e.g.

```
git show-branch master dev newbranch
```

which allocates a column per branch.